# reading new line from file and writing to another file in C++ using streams. not reading new line

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I am reading IO streams in C++ and have following code

```
int main() {
     
    fstream output_file;
    output_file.open("cout.txt", ios::out);
    fstream input_file;
    input_file.open("cin.txt", ios::in);

    // backup existing stream buffers 
    streambuf* cin_old_streambuf = cin.rdbuf();
    streambuf* cout_old_streambuf = cout.rdbuf();

    // Get output stream buffer of file and redirect to cout
    streambuf* output_file_streambuf = output_file.rdbuf();
    cout.rdbuf(output_file_streambuf);

    // Get input stream buffer of file and redirect to cin
    streambuf* input_file_streambuf = input_file.rdbuf();
    cin.rdbuf(input_file_streambuf);
    

    /* What ever you do with cout will write to file. */
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << line;
}
```

My input file `cin.txt`

```
My name is 
ravi
My age is 
45
```

output file `cout.txt` is

```
My name israviMy age is 45
```

My question is why program is not reading \n in input. My understanding is that `getline` reads newline. I am expecting output file is similar to input file. Kindly help what change do I have to main

Comment: `My understanding is that getline reads newline.`: It does extracts it from the stream, but doesn't append it to the string.

Comment: So you just have to add it back again in the output `cout << line << '\n'; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `getline(cin, line);` does retrieve the input from your other file line by line, if you want new lines when printing with `cout << line;` you should still follow the standard of adding either `"\n"` or `endl;` at the end of your `cout` lines.

The last part of your code should look like this.

```
getline(cin, line);
cout << line << endl;
getline(cin, line);
cout << line << endl;
getline(cin, line);
cout << line << endl;
getline(cin, line);
cout << line << endl;
```